# Simple function sequence for measurable functions with range $[0,1]$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $[0,1]$ have the usual topology.  Consider $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f$ is measurable.  Fix $n$.  I want to show that there is a measurable simple function $\phi_{n}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in X}|f(x) - \phi_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.
\end{align}

Comment: You want to show that the simple functions are dense in $L^\infty$?

Comment: By constructing a specific $\phi$ that does it in this specific manner.

Comment: f should be supported in a set of finite measure, since simple function does so.

Comment: See this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949086/approximating-measurable-functions) to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to Sky's comment, here's a hint.

$f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{k}{2^{n-1}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll give this a whirl later on.